# program to print armstrong numbers between two integers in c.Not able to find error in code

Tags: c

I wrote the following code to print armstrong numbers between two integers. But I am not able to find the mistake as the code looks fine to me. Please help.

```
void main()
{
    int a,b;
    printf("Enter the starting limit");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Enter the ending limit");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    int i;
    int sum=0;
    for(i=a+1;i<b;i++)
    {
        char word[50];
        sprintf(word,"%d",i);
        int temp=strlen(word);
        int j;
        for(j=0;j<temp;j++)
        {
            int c=i%10;
            sum+=pow(c,temp);
            i=i/10;

        }
        if (sum==i)
        {
            printf("%d",i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `pow` is using floating point and might for example produce `24.9999999` instead of `25`.

Comment: Is there any alternative you might suggest?

Comment: For integers it is just multiplication, for example `pow(5,3)` is the same as `5*5*5`.

Comment: what was the mistake in my code?

Comment: This `if (sum==i)` is in conflict with what Bo mentions in the first comment, which is caused by using `pow()` for integers logic. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken?s=1|1451.3580 which might be considered a duplicate.

Comment: what should i do to remove this problem?

Comment: @James - Phrasing it differently, instead of `pow(5,3)` you could use `5*5*5`. Unlike floating point calculations, integer math always produces whole numbers without rounding errors.

Answer (score 0):

As someone has answered - I will answer as well. Use only the integer arithmetic. No strings or doubles needed

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned long long ull;    // for convenience only


ull sum_cubes(ull num)
{
    ull result = 0;
    while(num)
    {
        unsigned digit = num % 10;
        result += (ull)digit * digit * digit;
        num /= 10;
    }
    return result;
}

#define MIN  0           //or 100 depending if 001 is the 3 digints number or not.
#define MAX  1000


int main(void)
{
    for(ull num = MIN; num < MAX; num++)
    {
        if(num == sum_cubes(num))
        {
            printf("Hurray!! Found - %llu\n", num);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just saying, but if the number and the sum of the cubes of its digits are equal, the number is Armstrong only if the number is a 3 digit number. I suppose the OP used `strlen()` to find the number of digits.

Comment: @J...S  Yea very difficult to change indeed. Change MAX to 1000 and you may change typedef from the `unsigned long long` to `unsigned`

Answer (score -1):

You use `i` in the control expression of the outer `for` loop but in the inner loop you are modifying `i` with the `i=i/10;`.
Even a single execution of that line will ensure that the value of `i` is lesser than its initial value.
Then this modified `i` is incremented with the `i++` in the outer `for` loop. 
If `a` is less than `b`, `i<b` will always be true, resulting in an infinite loop.

But since you have the number in the form of string in `word`, you could use that.

```
 for(j=0;j<temp;j++)
 {
     int c=word[j]-48;
```

The `-48` is used to convert the encoded character value (eg: 2 in ASCII is 50) to the actual number. If the encoding you use is not ASCII, you might have to do something different.

You could also make a copy of `i` before entering the inner loop and use that variable instead of `i` in the inner loop like

```
    int t=i, j;
    for(sum=j=0;j<temp;j++)
    {
        int c=t%10;
        sum+=pow(c,temp);
        t=t/10;
    }
```

You are not resetting the value of `sum` to `0` before each iteration of the inner loop. You could do that in the first part of the loop (ie, before the first semi-colon) as in the above loop.

Also as pointed out by [Bo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/597607/bo-persson), `pow()` returns a `float` and due to reasons expounded [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), inaccuracies might creep in.

So make the type of `sum` to be `float` instead of `int`.

Use of `void` as the return type of `main()` is not considered good practice. Use `int main()` instead. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/207992/5375464).

The part where you take the digits using `%` operator is also a mistake.

```
 int c=i%10;
```

On all iterations of the inner loop, value of `c` would be the last digit of `i` and you won't get any other digit in `c`.